# Use buttons to move circle without overlapping frame boundaries

Tags: java, frame, geometry

I have to create a program which moves the circle using buttons , it moves , but the circle passes the frame boundaries. I have tried lots of things but I'm afraid I should have organised the classes differently or I'm missing smth . Here the code that moves the circles without the conditions about overlapping.

The Circle class.

```
public class Circle extends JComponent {
Ellipse2D.Double e;



public Circle ()
{
     e=new Ellipse2D.Double (30,30,50,50);

    }

public void paintComponent (Graphics g)
{
    Graphics2D g2=(Graphics2D) g;
    g2.setColor(Color.RED);
    g2.fill(e);

}



public void moveUp()
{

    e.setFrameFromCenter(e.getCenterX(), e.getCenterY()-10,e.getX(), e.getY()-10);
    repaint();
}

public void moveDown()
{
    e.setFrameFromCenter(e.getCenterX(), e.getCenterY()+10,e.getX(), e.getY()+10);
    repaint();
}

public void moveRight ()
{
    e.setFrameFromCenter(e.getCenterX()-10, e.getCenterY(),e.getX()-10, e.getY());
    repaint();

}

public void moveLeft()
{
    e.setFrameFromCenter(e.getCenterX()+10, e.getCenterY(),e.getX()+10, e.getY());
    repaint();

}
}
```

The Main class

```
    public class Main{


public static void main(String[] args) {
    final JButton button1;
    final JButton button2;
    final JButton button3;
    final JButton button4;
    JPanel panel;
    final JFrame frame=new JFrame();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(500,200);
    final Circle c=new Circle();
    frame.add(c);


    button1=new JButton(" Right ");
     button2=new JButton(" Left ");
     button3=new JButton(" Up ");
     button4=new JButton(" Down ");
     panel=new JPanel();
     panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
     panel.add(button1,BorderLayout.WEST);
     panel.add(button2,BorderLayout.EAST);
     panel.add(button3,BorderLayout.NORTH);
     panel.add(button4,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
     frame.add(panel,BorderLayout.EAST);




    class ListenerClass implements ActionListener {
     public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
     {

         if (e.getSource()==button3)
         {
             c.moveUp();
         }

         else if (e.getSource()==button4)
         {
             c.moveDown();
         }
         else if (e.getSource()==button1)
         {
             c.moveRight();
         }
         else if (e.getSource()==button2)
         {
             c.moveLeft();
         }


     }
 }

ListenerClass listen=new ListenerClass();
button1.addActionListener (listen);
button2.addActionListener (listen);
button3.addActionListener (listen);
button4.addActionListener (listen);
}

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

So what you need to do is check boundaries. Essentially you need a simple collision/overlap check. here is a small change to the circle class that should help elaborate.

```
double moveSpeed = 10;
public void moveUp() {
    if(e.getBounds().getMinY() - moveSpeed >= 0){  // make sure the future location of the circle is within bounds of visual frame
        e.setFrameFromCenter(e.getCenterX(), e.getCenterY() - moveSpeed, e.getX(),
            e.getY() - moveSpeed);
    }
    repaint();
}
```

Now this answer isn't truly complete. For instance what happens if the top of the circle is 9 pixels away from the top of the screen  i.e.  e.getBounds.getMinY == 9  then since it checks in steps of 10 it would see that e.getBounds.getMinY - moveSpeed = -1 < 0  which won't let it move. You can solve this using the Math.min(double x, double y). in this case and Math.max(double x, double y) in the case of circle move down.

```
    double moveSpeed = 10;
    public void moveUp() {
        moveDistance = Math.min(y, moveSpeed);
        if(e.getBounds().getMinY() - moveDistance >= 0){  // make sure the future location of the circle is within bounds of visual frame
            e.setFrameFromCenter(e.getCenterX(), e.getCenterY() - moveDistance, e.getX(),
                e.getY() - moveDistance);
        }
        repaint();
    }
```